# 'Undefined' value when outputting value of a django modelform field

Tags: jquery, ajax, django

I am logging the value of the `city` field from `LocForm` but after entering a value and hitting the submit button, `$('#post-text').val()` is returning `undefined` as its value. The console output is:

```
form submitted!
create post is workin
undefined
```

Here are the main parts of code:

views.py:

```
def home(request):
    form = LocForm()
    context = {
        "form" : LocForm
    }
    return render(request, 'home.html', context)
```

forms.py: (form)

```
class LocForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Location
        fields = ['city']
        labels = {
            'city': ('Where do you want to live'),
        }
        widgets = {
            'city': forms.TextInput(attrs = { 
                'id': 'post-text', 
                'required': True
            }),
        }
```

main.js: (Main javascript file)

```
$('#post-form').on('submit', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log("form submitted!")
    create_post();
});

function create_post() {  //AJAX call
    console.log("create post is workin");
    console.log($('#post-text').val());
    });
};
```

Form's html code from template:

```
<form id="post-form" action="/create_post/" method="post" style="text-align: center">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form|crispy }}
    <input class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: Firstly you don't need the `document.ready` handler inside the `create_post` function so you can remove that. Secondly where in your HTML code is the `#post_text` element?

Comment: It is the `$(document).ready` that is causing your problem. @rory-mccrossan OP is setting a custom id of `post-text` to the field in the form class.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan It was my first question on stack overflow, so thanks for the editing :) and I've removed document.ready but still no effect. `#post_text` is id for an element inside `LocForm`, which i have imported inside `<form>` tag with `{{ form|crispy }}` . I've also added my views.py for providing more details.

Answer (score -1):

There are few points that need to be reviewed with your code:

- The usage of **$(document).ready()** :

You are currently using document ready inside your function create_post(). Which in your case is not useful. What you want is to be sure that your document is ready to catch your submit event, so it should be done before.

```
function create_post() {
    $(document).ready(function(){ ... });
};
```

Become:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#post-form').on('submit', function(event) {
          create_post();
    });
});
```

- The usage of **your id "post-text"**

From the code you provided, we cannot really id **post-text** is correctly used.
You should check the accessibility to this element in your console by typing:

```
$('#post-text');
```

And then

```
$('#post-text').val();
```

Comment: `$('#post-text');` is giving this output : `Object { context: HTMLDocument → 127.0.0.1:8000, selector: "#post-text" }` and `$('#post-text').val();` is giving this output : `undefined` . Also  I've removed `document.ready` but still no effect.

Comment: In that case it sounds like you have multiple elements with the `id` of `post-text` when there should be only one.